# C++ comparison of integers with float

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, comparison-operators

I have the following code.that demonstrates the problem I am having. How come the comparison is not evaluating to true? Is this a limitation of integer and floating point comparisons?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    double m = -0.625;
    if((-1)<=m<=0){
        std::cout << "Enter here" <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't chain comparison operators like that in C++, or in most languages. Python is the only language I know that allows it.

Comment: ahhh I see....This would explain why

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do three way comparison like that in C. Change it to the following and it'll work:

```
if((-1) <= m && m <= 0){
        std::cout << "Enter here" <<std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in this if statement

```
if( ( -1 ) <= m <= 0 ){
```

is equivalent to

```
if( ( -1 <= m ) < = 0 ){
```

as `-1` is less than `m` then the subexpression `( -1 <= m )` yields 1 in C and `true` in C++ that then is converted to 1 and the subexpression `1 <= 0` yields `0` in C and `false` in C++..

To get the expected result you should write instead

```
if( -1 <= m  && m <= 0 ){
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `-1 <= m <= 0` is equivalent to `(-1 <= m) <= 0`.

In this example, `-1` is implicitly converted to a `float` in order to use the `<=` operator with `m`. The result of this expression is a `bool`. This result is then implicitly converted to an `int` in order to use the `<=` operator with `0`. Since a bool is converted to either `0` or `1` (`false` or `true`), this conditional statement will only be true when `m` is less than `-1`.

It makes sense from a math standpoint to structure the if statement like that, however you must break it up explicitly so the compiler knows what you want.

Try this

```
-1 <= m && m <= 0
```